# jScript/HTML5 - What's the difference between localStorage.setItem & localStorage.variable = x?

Tags: javascript, html, jscript

So I'm curious what the difference is between those two:

```
localStorage.setItem('name', 'value');
and
localStorage.name = 'value';
```

It could be me who have misunderstood the whole localStorage part.
I'd really appreciate help with this as I'd like to know what to use to have it as efficient as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing really, localStorage is an object, so dot notation is OK, but it also has built in methods, and I personally like using those, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: [Here's a test for you on speeds](http://jsperf.com/local-storage-definition).

Comment: Thanks. I cannot put this as solved because I can't choose anyones reply as solved. :c